# Joining 2 tables indirectly through a relationship table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to fetch the genres related to a band through a relationship table. Is there any way to utilize JOIN to connect the genres table through the band_genre table?    Obviously this  is easily achievable using multiple queries, but I'm wondering just how elegant this sort of query can be.

Thanks :)

```
# (Bands) Table

band_id = 1
band_name = The Roots

# (Genres) Table

genre_id = 1
genre_type = Hip-hop

genre_id = 2
genre_type = Soul

# (Band_Genre) Table

bg_id = 1
bg_band = 1
bg_genre = 1

bg_id = 2
bg_band = 1
bg_genre = 2
```

Comment: What is your expected output, and what have you tried?  With a 50% acceptance rating, we're not here to do the work for you.

Comment: I was having trouble with trying to figure out how to make it so the output merges the multiple rows of genres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Bands b
INNER JOIN Band_Genre bg ON b.band_id = bg.bg_band
INNER JOIN Genres g ON bg.bg_genre = g.genre_id
```

Comment: Is there any way to merge the genres to be set as a single variable for each band so the output doesn't result in duplicate rows?

Comment: I don't believe there is any good way to do what you want there.  I think the best option would be to programmatically parse the results, and aggregate the Genres in the PHP, rather than trying to get MySQL to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the kind of query you want...

```
SELECT `band_name`, `genre_type`
FROM `bands`
INNER JOIN `band_genre` ON `band_id` = `bg_band`
INNER JOIN `genres` ON `genre_id` = `bg_genre`
```

...But I wasn't sure what you were asking about the JSON. So maybe this won't work for you.